# Restkit unit testing mapping to array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, mapping, restkit-0.20, xctest

I am trying to test the RestKit object mapping to an array of elements using RKTestFixtures.

When I try testing just 1 element of my Tutorial-object (which has a name and a description), everything works fine using the test-method below.

```
- (RKObjectMapping *)tutorialMapping {
    RKObjectMapping *objectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Tutorial class]];
    [objectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
            @"name" : @"name",
            @"description" : @"description"
    }];
    return objectMapping;
}

- (void)testMappingOfDescriptionWithValue {
    RKMappingTest *mappingTest = [RKMappingTest testForMapping:[self tutorialMapping] sourceObject:self.parsedJSON destinationObject:nil];
    [mappingTest addExpectation:[RKPropertyMappingTestExpectation expectationWithSourceKeyPath:@"description"
                                                                        destinationKeyPath:@"description"
                                                                                     value:@"This is an example description"]];
    XCTAssert([mappingTest evaluate]);
}
```

But, when I try testing an array of Tutorial-objects like the one below using evaluationBlocks, I can't get the mapping right...

```
[
    {
        "name": "Tutorial name 1",
        "description": "This is an example description"
    },
    {
        "name": "Tutorial name 2",
        "description": "This is an example description"
    }
]
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem? Google didn't get me right through it...

**UPDATE**

I am sending my JSON using the Fixtures feature:

```
NSBundle *testTargetBundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
[RKTestFixture setFixtureBundle:testTargetBundle];

self.parsedJSON = [RKTestFixture parsedObjectWithContentsOfFixture:@"tutorials.json"];
```

And in my test-method:

```
RKMappingTest *mappingTest = [RKMappingTest testForMapping:[self tutorialMapping] sourceObject:self.parsedJSON destinationObject:nil];
```

Comment: Try turning on trace logging and using `evaluateExpectation:error:` so you can see what `error` is returned.

Comment: Log message returns:
`Expectations: ()
Events: (
    "RKMappingTestEvent mapped sourceKeyPath 'imageUrl' => destinationKeyPath 'imageUrl' with value: (null)>",
    "RKMappingTestEvent mapped sourceKeyPath 'description' => destinationKeyPath 'description' with value: (null)>"
): map '(null)' to '(null)', but did not.}`

for mappingTest:

`[mappingTest evaluateExpectation:[RKPropertyMappingTestExpectation expectationWithSourceKeyPath:nil destinationKeyPath:nil evaluationBlock:^BOOL(...) { return true;}] error:&error];`

Comment: How are you supplying the JSON to the test? Have you checked (logged) it when running the test?

Comment: I haven't really helped yet :-) I'm just trying to get evidence that all of the inputs to the test are correct (hence the request for logging inputs and errors).